# emacs unicode character input on windows

Tags: windows, emacs, unicode

In an effort to make my emacs key chords shorter,
I've started to use one more modifier key - the Mode_switch(AltGr):

I've bound Mode_switch to ; and the a-z to α-ζ.
Thus I've got shortcuts like ;+β etc.

This works nicely on Ubuntu, but there's a problem on Windows:

the unicode characters entered into emacs display as ?.

Unicode input works in notepad.exe, the problem is just with emacs.

One curious thing is that μ is entered properly, and β is transformed to ß.
The problem isn't with Greek chars either, when I toggle-input-method to Greek,
I can enter them(in the usual way, not with Mode_switch).

Can anyone give me a shortcut to solve this problem?
The long way, I guess, would be to see how toggle-input-method is implemented.

Comment: Are you sure the font you're using support Unicode?

Comment: if you use `C-u C-x =` on a char that is displayed as `?` do you see if that char is still unicode? If you open a file with unicode chars saved from notepad, is it shown correctly by emacs?

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problems with unicode box drawing symbols.

Check out your font in windows. Run charmap windows utility, then choose
font, used in emacs (M-x describe-font).

You can get good font with wide unicode support [there](http://dejavu-fonts.org/wiki/Download)

Comment: The problem isn't the font. As I've said, the font handles the chars when I toggle-input-method to Greek. The problem is somehow locale related.